# Node.js - Nock and nedb - Reply gets executed before the call back finishes

Tags: node.js, nedb, nock

I'm using nock to intercept calls to my API host and do some local db look-ups before returning the response.

Please refer the below code. I intercept calls to 'entrypoint' and would like to reply with the data fetched from local datastore.

I believe this is a problem with nock module itself and I heard few suggestions to use streams. Can you please help overcome this problem?

```
// ... Code Block

var nock = require('nock'),
    request = require('request'),
    DataStore = require('nedb'),
    db = new DataStore({filename: './nedb.data'});

db.loadDatabase(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});

db.insert ({'record1': { "key1" : "value1"} });
db.insert ({'record2': { "key2" : "value2"} });
db.insert ({'record3': { "key3" : "value3"} });
db.insert ({'record4': { "key4" : "value4"} });
db.insert ({'record5': { "key5" : "value5"} });

var n = nock('http://localhost:8000')
            .get ('/entrypoint')
            .reply (200, function () {
                db.find ({}, function(err, docs) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    return docs;
                });
            });

request('http://localhost:8000/entrypoint', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log ('\nBEGIN: Body: ');
        console.log(body);
        console.log ('\n\nEND: Body: \n\n');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible at the moment, I have created this bug to start fixing this problem.

https://github.com/pgte/nock/issues/283